# Remove and append DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, append

I want to add and remove the element from the DOM . For remove I am using JQuery remove() function . Before removing the element I am coping that element using clone() method :

```
element = $("#list-view").clone();      
$("#list-view").remove();
```

This is working perfectly . But In another case I want to append the same element to the DOM again . So I am using the element which I have cloned earlier :

```
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(element);
```

But nothing is happening while appending the element . Am I missing anything ?

Comment: You could simplify your logic using `.detach()`  https://api.jquery.com/detach/  Be aware than using `.detach()` data will be kept, as e.g, handlers bound to element or children. This is usually preferred/more suitable method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`element` is a jquery object, not a dom element so use

```
element.appendTo('#container')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/96LAa/)

In your console you should be getting the error `Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/96LAa/1/)

Comment: Actually I am using this on mobile so I cant see the error log :(